# I can't install Delphi Chromium Embedded rev. 306 on Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, chromium, tchromium, chromium-embedded

So I downloaded the DCEF-R306 folder and placed it somewhere.

I heard this wouldn't be the latest edition, that should be something called DCEF3, but I saw DCEF3 didn't have anything in the \bin folder so I decided to try this one.

I'm quite new at Delphi 7. Programmed in BP7 when I was a kid. Long time ago.

Here's what I did:

1st attempt:
a) Went to Install Components and installed DCEF_D7 with cefreg unit. I don't have any idea what's the unit doing around the package, but I just went forward.
At this point the path to packages appears on the Library path in Environment Options.
b) Opened guiclient project from demos\guiclient
Compilation fails with `"File not found: 'cef.inc'"`
c) Replacde cef.inc with `..\..\src\cef.inc`
Compilation fails with `"File not found 'ceflib.dcu'"`
d) Revert reference back to `cef.inc`.

So I said, it can't see the units.

2nd attempt:
a) Opened guiclient project from demos\guiclient.
b). Went to Install Components and install the DCEF_D7 with cefreg unit
Main compiles but can't run ("Cannot debug project unless a host application is defined")
Alas, project becomes "DCEF_D7"...

3rd attempt:
a) Made a separate copy of the guiclient folder somewhere else (myfiles\delphi7\guiclient).
b) Copied inside the *.dcu and cef.inc from \src.
Compilation fails: `"File not found 'ceffilescheme.dcu'"`.
c). Further copy into myfiles\delphi7\guiclient folder everything from \demos\filescheme.
Compilation fails: "Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 00000000".
File main.pas becomes readonly.

4th attempt:
Further copy into myfiles\delphi7\guiclient folder everything from 
\bin\Win32 (including locales).
Same compilation failure with "Access violation at address 00000000. Read of address 00000000".
File main.pas becomes readonly.

I don't know what to do anymore, and I need it, because the webbrowser IE component is unusable.
Delphi 7 runs in Windows 2000 compatibility mode on Server 2008 R2.

Comment: 1) once you installed a design-time package (what sounds you did), you need to let the IDE know where the source code is. That's what you can do from `Tools / Environment Options...` menu. In the newly opened dialog go to tab `Library` and at the `Library path` edit field press the browse `...` button. Into the edit field insert path to the Chromium `\src` folder and press `Add` and then twice `OK`. You should then be able to compile the project. 2) the compiled project needs to *see* the files from the `\bin\Win32\` folder of the Chromium project, so don't forget to do something for that.

Comment: Hi TLama, done this  
Opened the guiclient from its original location (demos\guiclient).
Went to Tools\Environment Options and pushed the ... button.
Last path was grayed (src\packages)
So I cut the \packages there, and pushed Replace.
Now the path looked black.
Compile crashes the same "Access violation..."

Which means that it was able to see the units, but something trashes the compiler!
Alas, output directory in Project Options is ..\..\bin\win32 , which should be correct, (parent of guiclient, parent of demos,
then  to bin and win32)